# ngrok: using a localhost subdomain

Tags: ngrok

My localhost is accessed via `http://inter.localhost` .  I tried running ngrok via `ngrok http 80` but it tunnels directly to `localhost` rather than `inter.localhost` .  Is this only possible with a paid account?

Comment: Haven't used ngrok, but from looking at the docs... have you tried `ngrok http inter.localhost:80`?

Comment: thanks @Reed  yep, I tried that already and get `Make sure that a web service is running on inter.localhost:80 and that it is a valid address.`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ngrok http http://inter.localhost:80
```

This will create the tunnel to the specified one